# I need win32com.client.dispatch as multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pywin32, win32com

I want to dispatch a COM object using python `win32com.client.DispatchEx('***Something***')`

I want it done as multiple processes,
but currently when I launch this process twice, it always runs as a single process.

When I run the DispatchEx, I need two processes to be created in task manager with two process ID's.

Comment: can you add some code showing what you've already tried and any solutions that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to you, I test many pages in a similar way, opening them in a separate Chrome.webdriver and it works fine, the pages are independent of each other.

```
import concurrent.futures

name = ['James', 'Arnold', 'Jash', 'Johny', 'Harry', 'Michael']


def configer(name):
    i = 0
    b = 0
    while i == 0:
        print(b, name, '\n')
        b += 1
        if b == 10:
            i += 1


size = 6
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(size) as thp:
    thp.map(configer, name)
```

If you set the variable size to 2, you do not need to provide the function argument and the configer function will be executed twice simultaneously.
You can also create an if statement in the configer function, which executes if name = 'some_value', then you can start two threads simultaneously doing something completely different

This method above works with a high CPU load, so be careful of the CPU memory overflow